# Selenium not working except launching browser and open the page

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I see that my selenium cannot execute codes except to launch Chrome.

I don't know why my selenium is not working. It just open the browser (Chrome) with the URL and then doing nothing even to maximize the window, not even inserting the form.

Is there anything wrong with my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re, time, csv

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Ashraf%20Misran\\Installer\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Ashraf%20Misran/Devs/project-html/learning-html/selenium sandbox.html")
driver.maximize_window()
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//input")
username.click()
username.send_keys("000200020002")
```

The page I opened is coded as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sandbox</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="username">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried something similar like just get google.com?

Comment: Try to remove space from file name `selenium sandbox.html` -> `selenium_sandbox.html`

Comment: The page is successfully opened as explained in the question... but other command are not executed.

Comment: This typically means that the driver and browser version are not compatible. Make sure you update your browser fully, download the current version of Selenium and the current browser driver and try again.

Comment: post the page you're trying to open, it can be helpful

Comment: Done add the coded for the target page

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with web-page, you are trying to open. Would suggest to try first with simple test, like Open Google page, enter something in search field. With this you will be able to verify, if you correctly implemented driver initialization.

Update: try to use this css selector: **input[name='username']**, if page is loaded correctly, then you have a problem with your web element selector.

Comment: The page is successfully opened as explained in the question... but other command are not executed.

Comment: I updated my answer. Seems, that you have incorrect xpath. I wrote an example of css selector, which should work. Also, are there any messages/errors in console displayed? I think should be something, what can help with problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is a problem with using relative xpath locator. Please try that one:

```
username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input"))
```